# How to double the gutter width in larger breakpoints with Susy 2?

Tags: css, sass, breakpoints, susy-compass

I would like to have `1/4` size [gutter widths](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/settings/#gutters) in smaller breakpoints, then in larger breakpoints and above, I'd like the gutters to be set to `1/2`.

How can I globally set this in a `_variables.scss` file instead of having to declare it in every `susy-breakpoint()` (there's a ton of those)?

Seems like something like below should work, but it's throwing an error.

```
$susy: (gutters: 1/4);

@include susy-breakpoint($large-width, $large-columns) {
  $susy: (gutters: 1/2);
}
```

> [17:56:33] DEPRECATION WARNING on line 50 of _variables.scss:
>   Assigning to global variable "$susy" by default is deprecated. In
>   future versions of Sass, this will create a new local variable. If you
>   want to assign to the global variable, use "$susy: (gutters: 1 / 2)
>   !global" instead. Note that this will be incompatible with Sass 3.2.

Using `$susy: (gutters: 1/2) !global;` doesn't work -- it just ignores the 1/2 in larger breakpoints and uses 1/4 instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just watched a [Sass Bites episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m7k-vBzebPg) featuring Eric M. Suzanne and figured it out based on one of his examples:

```
$susy: (gutters: 1/4);

$large-width: 960px;
$large-settings: (gutters: 1/2);

@include susy-breakpoint($large-width, $large-settings) {
}
```